# Why wont ngRoute now work and breaks all other Angular functionality?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to us ngRoute to inject HTML into my web page but it doesn't work.

I have the below in my main html document.

```
<main ng-view></main>
```

next i created a folder call views with two HTML files (news.html & sectors.html)

I have also included angular-route.min.js into my project correctly. All paths for all files are correct.

Next I set up my routes as below, but it renders a blank page and even breaks the rendering of any ng-includes I have implemented which previously worked. In addition, it also breaks all other Angular functionality like filtering. There are no errors in the console, it just seems that ngRoute wont work.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

$routeProvider
    .when('/sectors', {
        templateUrl: 'views/sectors.html'
    })
    .when('/news', {
        templateUrl: 'views/news.html',
        controller: 'primaryController'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/sectors'
    });

}]);
```

Any help welcome.

Comment: Did you include a <base> tag in your main html page?

Comment: hello Dillon. Thanks for your comment. A base tag .. going to where? I have followed the Youtube tutorial by NetNinja AngularJS Tutorial #16 - Views and Routes

Comment: @AI-76 nm, it appears you're not using HTML5 mode.  Is your ng-view still wrapped in an ng-app?

Comment: Yes I have ng-app-"app" on the body tag.

Comment: What is "Angular functionality link filtering"? Wht do you mean when you say it is broken?

Comment: @georgeawg Just a typo ... link for like.

Answer (score 0):

You can check templateUrl for the path to your html templates. Everything else seems correct.